# CSS border-radius clip color

Tags: css

Is there a way to set the color of the clipped space while using:

```
border-top-left-radius: 1em;
```

I want it to be a certain color but it is taking the color of the div behind it

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Could you edit your answer with more of an explanation, provide your HTML/CSS and a JSfiddle please.

Comment: One possible work-around might be to put a little div behind your clipped div, set its position to top-left and then colour that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your element is not positioned with a z-index, you can create and absolutely position a pseudo-element behind it that's as large as the corner radius (or as large as the element itself if you prefer):

```
.your-div::before {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;  /* Or 100% if you prefer */
    height: 1em; /* Or 100% if you prefer */
    background-color: <your-color>;
    content: '';
    z-index: -1;
}
```

If your element does have its own z-index, then `z-index: -1` on a child element or pseudo-element won't work, and you'll have to make a new element and position that element behind the one with the rounded corner instead. How you do that will depend on your layout.

Comment: Perfect, this is EXACTLY what I needed! You rock so hardcore right now. Thanks!!!